# What is difference between xmlrc_port and http_port parameter in Odoo configuration file?

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

What is the difference between `xmlrc_port` and `http_port` parameter which are used in Odoo configuration file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None. Odoo 12 only uses `http_port`.

`http_port` was introduced in the version 11, prior to that, the parameter was `xmlrc_port`.

So, you should use

- `http_port` for Odoo >= 11
- `xmlrc_port` for Odoo < 11

In Odoo 12, `xmlrc_port` is kept for backward compatibility, see the mapping from `xmlrc-port` to `http_port` in the source code: https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/odoo/tools/config.py, line 147:

```py
group.add_option("--xmlrpc-port", dest="http_port", type="int", help=hidden)
```

You can find the documentation

- for Odoo 11, using `http_port`, here: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/cmdline.html
- for older versions, for example, Odoo 10, using `xmlrc_port` here: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/cmdline.html